# Nomenclature in Other languages

Tags: nomenclature, reference-request

Even one letter can make a huge difference in Chemistry Nomenclature. So I am looking for credible resources that is specifically published for explaining Nomenclature rules, examples in Spanish. Any suggestions?

Comment: By quick google search I found [this web page](http://www.chem.qmul.ac.uk/iupac/bibliog/books.html) where there are few titles in Spanish. For instance, there is a book entitled "Nomenclatura de la Química Orgánica (IUPAC)". Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: @Wildcat I was trying out that link before and after you have pointed out. However from U.Barcilona the pdf or the web page isn't loading. I looked for other avenues - no luck as of now. I am thinking a Spanish Chemistry book for Nomenclature might include the required info. However it's vital to get accurate nomenclature as of IUPAC though...

Comment: I do not speak any word spanish, but this might look promising: http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=Q_Z8RrSUuu8C&dq=Nomenclatura+de+la+Qu%C3%ADmica+Org%C3%A1nica+(IUPAC).&hl=de&source=gbs_navlinks_s You also might want to check your local organisation for more information: http://www.rseq.org/

Comment: That's indeed quite helpful, although it only covers the organic set.